# jhipster:entity error in jhispter:client or server app

Tags: jhipster

I created an app with jhipster:client and another one with :server and tried to generate an entity 'client only' in the client app but I'm getting:

```
'events.js:163
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'endsWith' of undefined
    at constructor.getAngularAppName (/Users/ndjordjevic/IdeaProjects/jh-client-jwt/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:1604:65)
    at constructor.getConfig (/Users/ndjordjevic/IdeaProjects/jh-client-jwt/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/entity/index.js:160:40)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ndjordjevic/IdeaProjects/jh-client-jwt/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:417:23)
    at /Users/ndjordjevic/IdeaProjects/jh-client-jwt/node_modules/run-async/index.js:25:25
    at /Users/ndjordjevic/IdeaProjects/jh-client-jwt/node_modules/run-async/index.js:24:19
    at /Users/ndjordjevic/IdeaProjects/jh-client-jwt/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:418:9
    at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)'
```

It works in 'server only' app.

Generating entities are only for 'full apps'?

Comment: This error means that the generator could not find your angular app name in  your .yo-rc.json file, you could try to add it manually.